# How to make SSO work on remote machine

Tags: ssh, kerberos, single-sign-on

I'm fighting with SSO and SSH on Debian Wheezy. Locally it works fine. I'm getting ticket successfully at login. But when I've logged in to the remote machine by SSH without password, `klist` on the remote machine finds no credentials. I tried to get more how-to, but I just know, that there must be enabled these options in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
    ...
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
    ...
```

Then each forwardable ticket should be sent. But it isn't. I tested by `klist -f` command, whether there is a F flag on the ticket. Yes, there is F shown. Despite I've to call `kinit` on the remote machine to get *endowed* with a key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm right, that these two options in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` are enough. But on client machine, not on the server, where I've been working all the time.